# Why does my SwingWorker lag/hang?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I recently looked into the whole SwingWorker thing and I found it quite useful so I decided to try it out but despite what everyone says - it continues to hang my application.

Here is my SwingWorker code:

```
    final ArrayList<Farm> farmz = dm.loadAll(item);
    SwingWorker<Boolean, Farm> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Farm>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < farmz.size(); i++) {
                publish(farmz.get(i));
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                boolean status = get();
                if (status) {
                    log.info("Completed loading!");
                    allModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                } else {
                    log.info("Failed to load...");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            }
        }

        protected void process(List<Farm> frm) {
            for (Farm farm : frm) {
                allModel.addRow(farm);
            }
        }

    };
    worker.execute();
```

I think I have followed everything properly but I'm still scratching my head over this one.

Comment: What's `dm.loadAll(item);` doing?

Comment: loadAll just parses a file.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/FCUvMi5H

Comment: And you don't think that might be "blocking" the EDT? Try putting that inside the doInBackground method before the for loop

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks!!! Wow.... SwingWorker is amazingly fast!

Comment: If it's any justice, it's loading over 3000 entries into a JXTable! :)

Comment: The only other issue you "might" have is with the `addRow` method, as this will want to update the UI after each row.  If you needed to, I would create a "batch" add method that would take a `List` add them all to the underlying model and fire a single update, but see how you go...

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Something like this, http://pastebin.com/xgKQae4b, @MadProgrammer ?